# html2canvas save SVG

Tags: jquery, html2canvas, canvg

I have a site where into a page I can click on a png and i load an SVg external. With a colorpicker I can change its color, with draggable and resizable I can change position and dimension of my SVG.
Now i want to save with html2canvas this SVG.
I know that html2canvas doesn't support SVG and for this I have to use canvg.
But how can I convert with canvg my dynamic SVG when I save?
Because I want that the image doesn't change position color or dimension.
Is possible?
How can I convert with canvg my dinamuc SVG?

this is my code (I have semplified because is very complex)
JQUERY:

```
//function that clone svg and insert into a div that will be saved
$('.insert-forme').click(function(){
        var obj = $('#'+$(this).data('svg')).clone();
        obj.attr('id',$(this).data('svg')+'_'+n_svg_created).css('width','100px').css('height','100px').find('svg').attr('width','100').attr('height','100');        

        obj.appendTo('#space-drawable-div').resizable({
            alsoResize: obj.find('svg'),
            containment: $('#space-drawable-div'),
            aspectRatio: true,
            maxWidth: 212,
            maxHeight: 220
        }).draggable({ 
            containment: $('#space-drawable-div')
        })
        n_svg_created++;
    });
//function that save the div where I have svg, text, image..
$('#save-tee').click(function(){
        var background = $('#space-drawable-div').css('background-color');
            html2canvas($('#space-drawable-div'), {
                background:$('#bg-tee').css('background-color'),
                logging: true,
                profile: true,
                useCORS: true,
                allowTaint: true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    var ajax_url ="<?php echo(site_url('/tee/save_tee')); ?>";
                    $.ajax({   
                        url: ajax_url, 
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: { 
                            imgBase64: dataURL,
                            title: title,
                            background: background,
                            type_tee:type_tee
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
    });
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/img/tee/forme/star.png" style="width:30px; margin-left:11px; cursor:pointer;" alt="forme" class="insert-forme" data-svg="star-svg" />

<div class="container-svg dynamic-element" id="star-svg" data-left="" data-top="" data-fill="">
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon class="svg" id="test" points="149.999,7.342 196.353,101.262 300,116.323 224.999,189.429 242.704,292.658 149.999,243.921 57.295,292.658 
 75,189.429 0,116.323 103.647,101.262 "/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: From html2canvas FAQ (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html) - Why isn't SVG images getting rendered? As with the previous question, SVG images taint the canvas with many browsers regardless of where they are hosted, or even if they are inline.